# Calculating the Exact Midline Between Two Shifted Sine Curves

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, curves

I have two identical sine curves, simply shifted by some value $y_0$.

**How can I find the exact midline between the two curves?**

If one takes the average of the y-values, you get *close* but if you look at this circle centered on the midline calculated in this way, it does not evenly touch both curves, showing the small error in the midline calculation.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question but if you have $\text{sin}(x)$ and $\text{sin}(x)+c$ then the the the middle line suggested by your picture is precisley $\text{sin}+\frac{c}{2}$. Maybe you need to clarify what you mean by midline between the curves.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the shortest line between two curves will always be where the perpendicular line to a tangent on one curve is also the perpendicular line to a tangent on the other curve.  This will be where the slopes are the same, so you could take the derivative of the sine waves and see where they are equal.  Since it is just a vertical shift the derivatives will be the same and x=x, but as your intuition is telling you, it won't be the same place on both curves, but where the top of one is near the bottom of the other. So at 90 + x deg and 270 - x deg for your circle

Comment: @Womm Yes but if you notice, the circle drawn on the "mid line" made in this way does not evenly touch both sides of the curves. I think there needs to be some sort of normal mid-line to make that work, maybe similar to what user78090 mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the OPs desire for the two primary curves to be parallel sine waves, I've developed an algorithm for the locus of circle centers that lie within the prescribed envelop. Note that the results shown below were developed for a proof of principle, rather than exact accuracy.

The crux of the method is outlined here:

1. Define the upper and lower curves, say

$$
y_{u,l}=\sin x \pm d \quad \text{ or }\quad z_{u,l}(t)=t+i(\sin t \pm d)
$$

2. Choose a point on the lower curve, say, $z_{l}(t_1)$
3. The unit normal vector to $z_{l}(t)$ is

$$
z_n(t)=i\frac{\dot z_l}{|z_l|}
$$

4. Guess the radius, $r$ of the desired circle and place it at $z_c=z_{l}(t_1)+rz_n(t_1)$. This circle will kiss the lower sine wave.
5. Iterate on $r$ until the circle just kisses the upper sine wave without crossing it.
6. Repeat for as many points along $z_l$ as desired.

Now, there are inherent problems with (a) machine accuracy, (b) curvature of the sine wave, (c) distance between curves, etc. Every calculation will have to be manually guided for a successful calculation.

I have implemented a quick and dirty brute force iteration for the proof of principle. There are two examples, with $d=0.5$ and $d=1$ that are shown below. Shown are the two sine waves, a sampling of embedded circles, the locus of the circle centers (in red), and the average of the two sine waves (in blue). The locus and the average are quite similar in both figures. But the correlation is deteriorated with increased spacing of the curves. We anticipate that will worsen with increased spacing or slope of the curves (e.g, $y=\sin 2x \pm d$).

[image: d=1/2]

[image: d=2]

Comment: This is great, thank you! I will try this method, I think this will fit my needs. Good idea to use the tangent circle iteratively to define the "mid line" rather than the other way around

Comment: I accepted this as "Solution" since it fits my needs, although I am still interested in a purely analytical solution to the midline problem if it is possible

Comment: Appreciated, I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: For some pairs of sine curves, there is a circle that is tangent to a local minimum of the upper curve and also tangent to the lower curve in two places. If you start the algorithm at a point on the lower curve between those points of tangency, as you grow $r$ you will get additional intersections with the lower curve before you reach the upper curve. You would need to detect this and omit any such point from the final result.

Comment: @DavidK I have found as I've continued with this algorithm, that I can just calculate the circles in one-fourth of the period of the sine wave and fill in the rest with mirror and reflective symmetries. I have not had problems such as you describe.

Comment: Certainly it is sufficient to compute one fourth of the period, starting from an appropriate point. The situation I describe is the top-to-bottom reflection of that shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4803315/139123); if you start at the maximum of the lower curve and go just one quarter cycle, you'll get a circle at every point, but if you start at the minimum of the lower curve there is no solution there.

Comment: @DavidK Okay, I see what you are saying, and you are indeed correct. You cannot start in a well because in most cases the circle will never to the min/max points on the bounding sine waves. In previous calculations I had switched to building off of the upper waves when I got there.

Comment: I think this is the best answer we can give to the question. I don't think there will be any analytic solution, at least not "analytic" in the sense OP would recognize.

Comment: I agree. I think with *ad hoc* cases you could probably fit a $2^{nd}$ or $3^{rd}$-order polynomial to the midline as defined here. I'll also point out the that that midline does not have continuous first derivatives at its peaks and troughs.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no answer but a question. Is the black point in this example part of what you consider the midline? Is it defined by the center line of tangent circles?
[image]

If your answer is yes, consider the following. The midline curve would be the same between the orange and blue curves, and between the blue and black curve. The midline curve so considered, is kind of a regularizer of the concave sections between the two curves...

[image]

Comment: Yes, the "mid line" as I am defining it should be through the centers of every tangent circle at every point discretized in the x-direction in the plot

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are looking at this is, at best, very difficult. My appraoch is perhaps the backward version. I start with a sine wave and build parallel curves above and below. This is very easy to do in complex variables. If $z(t)=t+i\sin t$, the upper and lower curves, at a normal distance $d$ from $z$, are given by

$$
z_{d^\pm}-z\pm id\frac{\dot z}{|z|}
$$

(A Cartesian version can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve).)

The figure below shows an example calculation with $d=.5$. Notice that the parallel curves are decidedly not either sine waves or equal to each other.

[image: ParallelCurveExample]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I need the two primary curves to be equal sine waves, just shifted by some y-distance.

Comment: I will follow this posting to see what happens. But I don't think there will be a solution of the type you would like.

Answer (score 0):

A mid-curve of given curvature $1/\rho$ can define two curves as having curvature radii of equal offset $c$

$$\rho \pm c $$

In this case the three curves have the same slope of their normals at respective points.

If the given two curves form one of two sets of orthogonal trajectories then it is possible to easily define a mid-curve.

But in general we need to know the commonality of the given lines so as to define the "mid-line".

I.e., integrands of a differential equation the arbitrary constant $0$ can be replaced by $\pm c/2$ in your sketched example.

In 3-space surfaces we have Bertrand parallel surfaces. The above suggestion is for the particular plane case.

Comment: Line 1 could be sin(x) and line 2 could be sin(x) + 10